# How can I populate array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert an array to an array of arrays.

For example if my array is:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want:

```
b = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you've already did it, no?

Comment: I dont understand your question?

Comment: this is the way to create a multidimensional arrays in JS: `b= [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` , http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/Wwwxm/

Comment: from a to b.
I have to convert to array like b??I mean it should be convert to tupple array

Comment: thank you Felix, yes its right

Answer (score 2):

```
function Create2DArray(rows) {
  var arr = [];

  for (var i=0;i<rows;i++) {
     arr[i] = [];
  }

  return arr;
}
```